# How to create OneToOne and OneToMany that are all linked together

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm coming from Front End so all this is new to me. I have the following entities `Client`, `Cart`, `Product` and they are connected between them as such:

1. `Client` <=> `@OneToOne` <=> `Cart`
2. `Cart` => `@OneToMany` => `Product`(`@ManyToOne` for `Cart`)

Running my `SpringDataJpaApplication` creates correctly all my 3 tables with all the respective columns and their foreign keys in Postgres. Creating a new `Cart` with all the fields, will create both the `Client` and `Cart`in the Postgres, but will not create the `Product` which is a `@ManyToOne`. Querying the database will generate empty fields for `Product`

```
// Client
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Client {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int client_id;

private String name;
private String lastName;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "client")
private Cart cart;
}


// Cart
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Cart {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int cart_id;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
private List<Product> productList;


@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_client_id", referencedColumnName = "client_id")
    private Client client;
}


//Product
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Entity
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int product_id;
    private String productName;
    private int price;
    private int qty;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "fk_cart_id")
    private Cart cart;
}


// CartController
@RestController
    public class CartController {

        @Autowired
        CartRepository cartRepository;

        @PostMapping("/createCart")
        public Cart createCart(@RequestBody Cart request) {
            return cartRepository.save(request);
        }
}
```

As mentioned, posting to the endpoint, returns a `200` with records (as mentioned above) only created for `Client` and `Cart`. The post request is as follow:

```
{
  "productList": [
    {
      "productName": "mobile",
      "price": 800,
      "qty": 2
    }
  ],
  "client": {
    "name": "John",
    "lastName": "Done"
  }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? Why isn't `Product` table populated?
(**Note:** With only `@OneToMany` and `@ManyToOne` between `Cart` and `Product` I'm able to populate both of them, but when the `Client` is thrown in to the mix, I have the issue describbed above)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of owning entity is what you are missing.

In the `Cart` entity you have:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "cart")
private List<Product> productList;
```

This says that the `Product` entity owns the relationship. Only the entity that owns the relationship can persist a relation. This means that a `Product` can persist a `Cart` but not visa-versa. In short, you have to persist a `Product` yourself. So, save the cart, then set the cart in the product, and save the product.

If you didn't have it then the `@ManyToOne` by itself dictates the same course of action.

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "fk_cart_id")
private Cart cart;
```

The `productList` should be considered as a query only field.

Note that you can play games with `Cascade` annotations in `Cart` but I do not recommend that. It is a somewhat complicated and vexing annotation. Instead of having a `Repository` in your `Controller` layer, create a `@Service` layer and put the persist, retrieve, and other business logic in there and include that in your controller. Standard pattern.

Then write junit/mockito test cases for your service layer.

EDIT: Just to be clear, a `Product` cannot persist a `Cart`, but rather must have a previously persisted `Cart` to set to the cart field. No such requirement for the `Cart` entity.

Comment: you were right, I was missing the part of relationship ownership. You mention that `Product` owns the relationship. Isn't that incorrect? Isn't it the cart?

Comment: It does seem backwards I guess, but notice that you have a `Cart` in `Product` but you have a `List` in `Cart`. The foreign key is created in the `Product` table so `Product` is the one responsible for and hence owns the relationship. The value in the fk_cart_id column in the product table is a persisted relation.